# How to define Entity inheritance in a yaml file when creating a User entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, fosuserbundle

FOS User bundle [states in its documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#a-doctrine-orm-user-class) that a newly created User entity must inherit to `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`.

An example in the docs displays how to define inheritance in the PHP entity, but once you click on the YAML tab, there is no trace of inheritance at all:

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

So I did some research and added `inheritance:` key to the definition:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    inheritance:
        extends: FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
        type: simple
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

It does work, but creates an empty User entity with the only `id` property, without any trace of inheritance again.

So the question is, how to create a YAML ORM file for the User entity that actually extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` entity?

Update.
I should have mentioned that if I use the exact YAML definition from the docs, without any inheritance,

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

XML
```

Then the outcome is the same - an entity with a sole id property:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * User
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: First time using the bundle?  If so you have my deepest sympathy.  Expect to spend far more time researching these sorts of issues then if you just wrote the functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the part of YAML it's part of the entity

check this documentation. [Doctrine ORM User class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#a-doctrine-orm-user-class)

YAML doesn't need inheritance for this purpose rather your entity should be inherited by `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`.

Update your schema you will get all field that defines in `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User.`

if you need an extra field or override existing then modify your user entity class.